# Forge viewer: Custom materials step-by-step

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've seen some examples of high quality and detailed models that works for the Autodesk Model Derivative. Some example are `Dotty`, `Dasher` and `Fusion Race Car`. [Dotty](https://trial.dotdotty.com/share/?shareId=cdc9-523f-305f-7ddb-5cc4) is actually amazing.. even has some reflection added in there.

So, to achieve this I would need to upload the textures and the materials with my model. I've tried to reproduce the guide telling me to create a ZIP containing of the OBJ, MTL and PNG. First of all, to be sure I am on the correct path when I am testing out different workflows: is OBJ the only format that can be uploaded with custom materials/textures? I know that I can add standard materials to rvt, fbx, 3ds etc, but I do not have a clear idea on how to upload custom materials/textures.

Could you kindly give me a step-by-step how to get the best possible visualization of the uploaded models? Thanks a lot

Comment: I am also experimenting with those kinds of workflows as well, to achieve the best possible visualization of our models. I am not an expert at all, but I know that the Forge viewer is build on top of three.js. Imagine if the models could be post-processing antialiasing like this: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_fxaa

Comment: In this video: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_cube - they have actually taken a scene from Unreal Engine 4 (called Sun Temple) and seamlessly integrated it into three.js. The quality and materials looks pretty much the same as in UE4 itself. Does this actually mean that it would be possible to achieve this kind in the Forge viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models from **Fusion 360** uses the built-in material library, in the case of `Fusion Race Car` you mentioned. The `Dasher` sample uses a **Revit** model of a "well-designed" model in Revit, but no custom materials. Don't have much info on the `Dotty` format, but would consider the direction of `obj` or `rcp` (Reality Capture or point cloud) files, both can have texture.

For a custom material, OBJ is the best route as of now, allowing you to include your textures. As far as Forge, the translation is exactly the same: upload the `zip` with all files and post a job with `rootFilename` pointing to the `.obj` file.

Comment: Note that by default the Autodesk viewer uses a progressive rendering pipeline that you can disable if you want to use something different. You can also create your own material shaders which is what Dasher does for the heatmaps, or alter existing materials assigned to object. I got couple of examples to do this. You can also include more lights and objects as you wish into the THREE.js scene, but you cannot really change the rendering pipeline itself.

Comment: @cyrille. Interesting. Would you kindly share those examples as well? Will definitely look into this.